# Testing Android APK on Blackberry running Android Jellybean

Tags: android, eclipse, blackberry-10, blackberry-android

A user is trying to test an app which I created on Eclipse with the Android Plug-in. They have a BB10 device that is running jellybean. The app has not been released yet so it is currently signed with a debug token. When they try to install the app (I sent them the APK file via email) using an APK installer, they get the error "The installation failed because signature verification failed". Is there anyway to fix this so they can run the app and test it on their device?

Comment: "BB10 device that is running jellybean". What this mean ?. BB10 running on android os ?

Comment: BB users who have found a way to get Android on their devices are not likely going to be your core customer base when you ship your app to the store. Would telling them to enable USB debugging, download Android SDK, install the Google USB driver, and then `adb install yourapp.apk` an option for them?

Comment: App needs to be signed, that's all.

Comment: @Signare, Wselbie: BlackBerry 10.2.1 support runing Android 4.2.2 APKs directly on the device using the Android runtime environment. Because the device is not running Android as the base OS adb is not an option.

Answer (score 1):

try using the commandline tool to convert and directly push it to BB device.

Answer (score 0):

To install an application that is only signed by a debug token, the device has to have that debug token installed on it.

The supported way to have customers 'beta' test a BB10 application is to sign it with your BlackBerry signing key, uploaded it to BlackBerry world, but don't submit it for approval. Add the BBID of the customer to your BlackBerry World sandbox. The customer can then enable development mode of the device, select development mode in BlackBerry World and enter the AppID or SKU of your application and get the latest version even if not yet approved.

The other option is to produce and sign a production ready APK with your Android development tools and send that to the customer.